# Snapshots setup via Device Mapper on Debian 11 doesn't work/reports error

Tags: debian, snapshot

I try to setup a Device Mapper snapshot according to the hints in the net and here on stackexchange. The TABLE entry is: "0 209711104 snapshot /dev/sdb1 /dev/loop0 P 16", the command: "sudo dmsetup create $NAME < $TABLE".
I get alwas the error: "device-mapper: reload ioctl on snap (253:1) failed: Device or resource busy".
Setting up a linear target with the TABLE "0 2097152 linear /dev/loop0 0" works.
I tried it on several PCs, real and VirtualBox, in Debian 11 and got always the same error.
As usually, any help appreciated, Hans